# MongoDb aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

How to write simial query using mongdoDb aggregation

```
select count(*) as ccount from a group by a.someField order by ccount desc limit 1
```

Using group function in mondoDb, I want to group my collection by specific key and return 1 row, which occurs more often

Code below in Java, return list, that was apply group by on field someField and return collection of elements, where every element has 2 fields, "someField" and "count" (number of occurrence) I would like to avoid second iteration on client side to find out maximum of counts

```
new GroupCommand(myCollection,
                 new BasicDBObject("someField ", true),
                 null,
                 new BasicDBObject("count", 0),
                "function(key,val){ val.count++;}", 
                 null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing like SQL's order or limit is available for MongoDB's group command. The aggregation framework in the current development release (version 2.1) provides $sort and $limit operators:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework

Comment: Update: The stable Mongo 2.2 release is now official and the aggregation framework is now available at production quality.

Answer (score 0):

In mongoDB 3 you can use limit and skip:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/