# MongoDB aggregation framework in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection and I need to find each distinct value in a field, and how many times each value occurs, a bit like the GROUP BY and COUNT functions in SQL.

e.g.

```
Item name ------ count

Soap ----------- 7
Apples --------- 4
Tin Foil ------- 5
```

I'm new to MongoDB and haven't really been able to find any documentation that can help me with this. So far, I've been able to return a list of distinct values, but not the count of each one.

I need to do this through the Java MongoDB library.

Comment: Have you seen: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation

Answer (score 2):

```
db.item.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$name",
        count: {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        name: "$_id",
        count: 1
    }
}
]).pretty();
```

A java implementation will be like this

```
    final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    final DB db = mongoClient.getDB("DB_NAME");
    final DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("item");

    final DBObject groupIdFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$name");

    groupIdFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));
    final DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupIdFields);

    final DBObject projectFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
    projectFields.put("name", "$_id");
    projectFields.put("count", 1);
    final DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", projectFields);

    final AggregationOutput aggregate = collection.aggregate(group, project);
```

Comment: @cpburnz you are right I was simply trying to put one answer. now I added the java implementation for it

Answer (score 1):

You can do [simple aggregation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation) using [count()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#count%28%29), [distinct()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#distinct%28java.lang.String%29), and [group()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#group%28com.mongodb.GroupCommand%29) commands via the [DBCollection class](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html) of the MongoDB Java driver.

For more advanced queries in the current production version of MongoDB (2.0.6) you can use [Map/Reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) via the [MapReduceCommand class](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MapReduceCommand.html).

In MongoDB 2.2 (which currently is being tested for release) there is a new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) feature.  The 2.9.0 release of the Java driver will include an [aggregation helper](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-590).

Comment: Aggregation helper will be available in version 2.9.0 (not 1.9.0). BTW, you can already use new Aggregation Framework with Jongo : http://jongo.org/#querying

Comment: @BenoitGuerout: Thx, off by 1 :-p.  Corrected.  The 2.9.0 Java driver isn't officially released yet, but it's possible to test with a github checkout of [mongodb-java-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a mongodb expert, but it seems a good place to use [MongoDB MapReduce capabilies](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) to perform aggregations or to take a look to this link about [aggregation in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation).

Related questions:

- [MongoDb aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387592/mongodb-aggregation)
- http://www.quora.com/How-do-you-write-aggregate-queries-in-MongoDB
- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/s11V8KaZcAE/discussion